# XTS apply function to time of day subset?

Tags: r, xts

How can I apply a summary function to a time of day subset?

For example with:

`r['T16:00/T17:00']$Value`

How can I apply something like `function (x) quantile(x, c(.90))` for Value over each day's sample hour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `apply.daily` to apply a function to each day's data after you've done the time-of-day subset.

```
rt <- r['T16:00/T17:00','Value']
rd <- apply.daily(rt, function(x) xts(t(quantile(x,0.9)), end(x)))
```

You can see I needed to do a few backflips to ensure the object returned from your function can be handled by `apply.daily`.  Mainly, it has to be a multi-column xts object with one row.

Comment: `plot(apply.daily(rt, function(x) quantile(x, c(.90))))` Works ... is there a caveat with that? -- Oh I see, typo in my question so you were going off of that I think

Comment: @KyleBrandt: You're correct.  I thought it was a bit odd, but I assumed you did it on purpose. :)  I'll update my answer.